# ATtiny167 Device not recognized

Tags: attiny85, digispark

I'm frustrated I feel like I am 90% there but my computer will not recognize the ATtiny167. Here i9s the list of things I have completed/tried using Windows 10 and Arduino 1.8.6;

```
                  1) Installed Driver USB Bootloader is complete
                  2) Device Management I see the device
                  3) Arduino Sketch select 16.5 MHz board in parameters
                  4) Led on the board flashes sound beeps and stops flashing
                  5) "Device not recognized"
                  6) I have rebooted many times. I deleted everything and started over again with same        
                      results
                  7) Used a 3rd party software to look at my USB ports it see the device 
                   I have tried more than one device as well

         I'm stuck at this point. I've tried running example programs however the device is not recognized.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have some code on the chip that makes it appear to be a USB device? Otherwise, do you have some USB to UART hardware for communicating with the chip? Is this something you have built yourself, or some non-standard development board?

Answer (score 1):

If Digispark Pro clone is not recognized, you can try to use/upload .ino programs via ArduinoISP.

note use in File -> Preferences -> Additional Boards Manager URLs: 
http://drazzy.com/package_drazzy.com_index.json 
instead:
http://digistump.com/package_digistump_index.json

(The first is AttinyCore by Spence Konde, the second is the normal Digistump AVR Boards)

Then selected Tools -> Boards Manager, and Find AttinyCore -> (Wait and Install).

Now you can upload File -> Example -> ArduinoISP on your Arduino connected in ISP mode with your ATtiny167.

Now select ATtiny167 Board, 16Mhz (External) and write bootloader with your Arduino connected in same manner ISP mode with your ATtiny167.

And now upload any .ino file for ATtiny167 in the same manner with your Arduino connected in ISP mode with your ATtiny167.